# What is the order of execution of declarations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function func(){
        }
        var foo="foo";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var foo="foo";
        function func(){
        }
</script>
```

At the beginning, when func is a function and foo is "undefined", but I want to know which is the first to be defined, func or foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers of both, variable and function declarations (and also formal parameters for *function code*) are made when *entering the execution context*, that's actually before the code execution.

In the case of variables, as you noted it, they are initialized with the *undefined* value at that stage, the assignment takes places after, when control reaches the assignment expression, e.g.:

```
var foo = "outer";
(function () {
  alert(foo); // undefined
  var foo = "inner";
})();
```

In the above code, we can see how the `foo` identifier holds the `undefined` value, that's because when entering the function execution context, the local `foo` variable was initialized.

That's one of the reasons why people recommend to declare your variables at the top of the function (to resemble what actually happens)

Functions declarations are also *hoisted*, you can actually use them before its declaration, because as we know, it was made before the code execution, for example:

```
func(); // "bar"
function func () {
  return "bar";
}
```

See also:

- [Variable Instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3) Process

Answer (score 1):

In

```
var foo = "foo";
function func() {
}
```

there are two things going on

1. Declaration
2. Initialization

`foo` and `func` are declared simoultaneously.

The initialization of `func` is hoisted to the top.  So functions are initialized before `var`s.

So the order of operations is

1. `foo` and `func` declared
2. `func` initialized to a `Function` object
3. `foo` initialized to `"foo"`

This is clearest in the code

```
var foo = bar;
function bar() {}
```

where after this code runs, `typeof foo === 'function'`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe identifiers become defined as their declarations are encountered.

Comment: Not true.  Declarations take effect before the first statement is executed.  For proof, consider `alert(foo); var foo = 1`.  This does not fail with an exception because foo has been defined, but it does not alert 1 either because foo has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in javascript are always parsed and defined first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('before func: ' + func);        // Print function as string
    alert('before somevar: ' + somevar);  // Print undefined

    function func() {
    }

    var somevar = "hello";

    alert('after func: ' + func);         // Print function as string
    alert('after somevar: ' + somevar);   // Print hello
</script>
```